# SEAM: Simple email mailto link

Tags: email, jsf, seam

This is probably a simple question, bu I just can't find the answer I'm looking for.  I have a Seam facelet page that I want want a string (that is an email address) to show up as link which when pressed, opens the users local email program with the email address in the to line

This what I have so far (the syntax is nor right):

> ```
>           <ui:define name="results">
>                 <a:form>
>                     <rich:dataTable
>                     var="_item"
>                     value="#{myView.addressBean.items}"
>                     <rich:column>
>                             <f:facet name="header">Type</f:facet>
>                             <h:outputText value="#{_item.address.addressDescription}"/>
>                         </rich:column>
>                     <rich:column>
>                             <f:facet name="header">Info</f:facet>
>                             <h:outputText value="#{_item.address.addressType.type eq 'email' ? [<a href="'mailto:' + #{_item.address.addressInfo}">#{_item.address.addressInfo}</a>]  : _item.address.addressInfo}"/>
>                         </rich:column>
>                     </rich:dataTable>
>                 </a:form>
>             </ui:define>
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an [`ui:fragment`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/fragment.html) (or an `h:panelGroup`), instead of `h:outputText`, like this:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{_item.address.addressType.type == 'email'}">
    <a href="mailto:#{_item.address.addressInfo}">#{_item.address.addressInfo}</a>
</ui:fragment>
```